# Maven dependency tree and pom dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I would like to know all transitive dependencies of the following jar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Moving a classic command to the pom.xml of the project's defining that dependency and inputting:

> mvn dependency:tree

would show:

```
+- org.codehaus.mojo:xmlbeans-maven-plugin:jar:2.3.3:compile
|  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
|  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  +- org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-2:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
|  |     +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
|  |     \- classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
|  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.4.0:compile
|  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
|  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6:compile
```

I don't see the mojo-parent:

```
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>mojo-parent</artifactId>
  <version>21</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

At first glance it seems that the mvn command can show the dependencies which are not pom type.

Is there a way to show exactly every single file needed to keep a jar alive?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it showing only compile time dependencies?

Comment: So it seems, but I would like to see everything of that jar (or each) of that project.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120294/how-do-i-show-the-maven-pom-hierarchy

Comment: Maybe effective-pom could help you!? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html

Comment: I still can't see the mojo parent listed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it's hard to show files needed to 'keep a jar alive'. Your project can have some implicit dependencies.

You can run `mvn dependency:analyze`, it should show you unused dependencies.
But you have realize which of them you can freely remove. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html

I can also recommend if you don't want any surprises with transitive dependencies - use maven enforcer. You can ban all undeclared transitive dependencies.
http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/banTransitiveDependencies.html

Comment: Interesting but I'm asking dependencies of a jar. the Project could be an empty one just to run the mvn command.

Comment: @Mark dependeny:tree is showing to you all required dependencies for jar. What do you need then?

Comment: I still can't see the mojo parent listed

Comment: @Mark that's because a parent pom is not a dependency.

Comment: @Mark as it was already mentioned - pom's wont be visible there. Parent poms affecting which version of artifacts will be used. Only way I know to see how it is affected - generate effective pom.